# Flaw in use of Schwarz's inequality: where is my error?

Tags: contour-integration, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For real functions of the real variable the Schwarz's inequality for integrals is given as [Brand Louis, advanced calculus, 1958, p.535]:

$\left(\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx\right)^{2}\le\int_{a}^{b}f^{2}\left(x\right)dx\int_{a}^{b}g^{2}\left(x\right)dx$

Let us apply the inequality to the following integral function of polar coordinates:

$I=\oint_{r_0}^{r_0}\frac{dr}{r}\sin^{2}\theta(r)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dr(\theta)}{d\theta}\frac{1}{r}\sin^{2}\theta d\theta$

where $r\left(\theta\right)$ is here seen as a function of $\theta$ with $r\left(0\right)=r\left(2\pi\right)=r_{0}$ i.e. it describes an arbitrary closed path in polar coordinates, as shown on the following figure:

[Image of the closed path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmswv.png)

To mean that the current point describes a contour in the polar plane before going back to its initial point, I have used the $\oint$ symbol.
For most choices of $r\left(\theta\right)$ it is easily checked numerically that $I\ne0$, contrary to e.g.

$\oint_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\frac{dr}{r}=\left[\ln r\right]_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}=\ln r_{0}-\ln r_{0}=0$

that is zero for any choice of path.
The Schwarz's inequality applied on I gives

$0\le I^{2}\le\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{1}{r}\right)^{2}d\theta\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sin^{4}\theta\right)d\theta$

Up to now it seems to be correct. But the first integral on RHS can be written «formally»

$0\le J=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{1}{r}\right)^{2}d\theta=\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{1}{r^{2}}dr=\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\left(\frac{d\theta}{dr}\right)^{-1}\frac{1}{r^{2}}dr$

where this time $\theta$ is seen as a function of r. It is clear that $\theta\left(r\right)$ is a multiple-valued function since $r\left(0\right)=r\left(2\pi\right)$ (at least two values of $\theta$ must correspond to an effective value of $r$ on the path), this is perhaps the reason why we are not allowed to use the Schwarz's inequality for J (see the question mark above the inequality):

$J^{2}\overset{?}{\le}\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\left[\left(\frac{d\theta}{dr}\right)^{-1}\frac{1}{r^{2}}\right]^{2}dr\int_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}1^{2}dr=0$

If anyway we suppose it is possible, from the obvious result (closed contour integral of a perfect differential)

$\oint_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}dr=0$

it leads indeed to the RHS being zero.
In turn this would lead to

$0\le I^{4}\le J^{2}\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\sin^{4}\theta\right)d\theta\right)^{2}=0$

giving $I=0$, which is false (I have checked numerically, as written above). Where am I incorrect? In the second application of the Schwarz's theorem (question mark)? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: my integral in $dr$ is exactly of the type (b) and (c) of this exercise in the book of Louis Brand:
[exercise text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNEih.png)
[exercise solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNjq9.png)

Indeed we have $\hat{r}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}=dr$ where:

- $\hat{r}$ is the unit vector in the direction of the origin to the current point (i.e. in the direction of the radius $r$ measured between the origin and the current point);
- $dr$ is the variation of $r$ between two neighbor points on the curve ($r$ defined just above).

If we want we can define the variation of curvilinear coordinate $s$ as $ds=\sqrt{d\vec{r} \cdot d\vec{r}}$).
As you can see in the result of exercise (c), if we put $r_1 = r_2$ we get zero. This is exactly the meaning of my integral:

$\oint_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\frac{dr}{r}=\left[\ln r\right]_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}=\ln r_{0}-\ln r_{0}=0$

A contour is described in the polar plane, $r$ starts from a point where $r=r_0$ and finally goes back to the same point where obviously $r$ has the same value $r_0$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your integral $I$ . It contains $dr$ and $d\theta$ and integrates $r$ over an interval of length zero ? This is clearly zero. The Schwartz inequality relates three integrals of the same type, not a double integral to the product of a $dr$ and a $d\theta$ integral.

Comment: @KurtG. I wanted to use "\landupint" to mean a path integral; I could have used "\oint". It means that $r(\theta)$ starts from $r_0$, describes a path in the polar plane, and returns to $r_0$. Is the second integral on the line defining $I$ clearer? I have given above the example of $dr/r$ that is indeed zero, but if you multiply by some arbitrary function of $\theta$ as I have done above in $I$, it is no more zero (I have checked numerically for a $r(\theta)$ function chosen randomly).

Comment: @KurtG. "Schwarz" please, not "Schwartz"!

Comment: @KurtG. Except if I am wrong, when I apply Schwarz theorem, I do not see any double integral or two integrals having a different variable of integration. The first time I apply the theorem, the variable of integration is $\theta$, the second time it is $r$.

Comment: @MartinR . Yep .  Named after [Karl Hermann Amandus Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz). Not to be confused with [Laurent Schwartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Schwartz) who pioneered the theory of distributions. Now getting back to OPs edited question.

Comment: Sorry, when I integrate a scalar function over a closed circle around the origin I don't get zero. This is the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition) to use. When we parametrize the circle by $\gamma(\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ we get $|\gamma'(\theta)|=r=const.$ and hence $\int_\gamma \frac{1}{r}$ (which you denote as $\oint_{r_0}^{r_0}\frac{dr}{r}$) becomes $\frac{1}{r}\int_0^{2\pi}rd\theta=2\pi\not =0.$

Comment: @KurtG. Except if I am wrong, my integral is of the type $\oint\frac{\hat{r}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}}{r}$ (, where here $\hat{r}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}=dr$, knowing that $\hat{r}$ is the unit vector corresponding to the position vector). Thus it seems to me that we are not talking about the same integral.

Comment: Maybe we don't . As far as I know however and what I said before the Schwarz inequality relates three integrals of the same type . I don't see that happening in your question.

Comment: @KurtG. My $dr$ is not the curvilinear coordinate variation, but the variation of the radius $r$ measured from the origin. This is different.

Comment: I am more than happy to look into this in detail. Before that however, please define your line integral unambiguously using one of the standard [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral). Best to look at a circle and use the obvious parametrisation. Then break this down into an ordinary integral. At the moment I have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: @KurtG. I have edited my question with an appendix to explain the meaning of my integral, referring to an exercise in the book of Louis Brand. This is exactly the same type of integral, i.e. "line integral of a vector field" in the Wikipedia page you points to.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP and I do not seem to find an agreement what integral is meant by OP exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I have discussed with a colleague about my original question. The problem is probably that $\theta$ is a multiple-valued function of $r$ (possibly "infinitely-valued" in the case of a circle), preventing to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality a second time as I did in my original post (but the first application of C-S inequality was correct). In fact I already wrote about that in my original post.
To remove this "multiple-valued" feature of $\theta(r)$, it is of course only needed to make $\theta$ depend on $\vec{r}$ instead. All in all, it is better to get rid of $r$ and use only $\vec{r}$ in the integral. So instead of

$I=\oint_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\frac{dr}{r}\sin^{2}\theta(r)$

we write

$I=\int_{\overrightarrow{r}_{1}}^{\vec{r}_{2}}\frac{\hat{r}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}}{r}\sin^{2}\theta\left(\overrightarrow{r}\right)=\int_{\overrightarrow{r}_{1}}^{\vec{r}_{2}}\frac{\overrightarrow{r}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}}{r^{2}}\sin^{2}\theta\left(\overrightarrow{r}\right)$

i.e. we use the notation of the exercise of the book "Advanced Calculus" of Louis Brand that I attached as image in the comments of the answer by Kurt G., and we take $\vec{r}_{1} = \vec{r}_{2}$ to mean that a closed path is described.
But clearly now we cannot apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that applies to a function of only one variable: $\theta(r)$.
A quick search on the web suggests that there are multidimensional versions of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality available. However I will not enter this topic as my original post is now answered clearly (to my mind).

Answer (score 0):

We clarified in the comments that your $I$ is a line integral
$$\tag{1}
I=\oint_\gamma \frac{\mathbf{r}\cdot d\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|}\,.
$$
I have learned when I parametrize this with a curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ it is evaluated as
$$\tag{2}
I=\int_a^{b}\frac{\gamma(t)\cdot\gamma'(t)}{|\gamma(t)|}\,dt\,.
$$
By assumption the curve $\gamma$ is closed: $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$.

Since in $\mathbb R^\color{red}{3}$ the vector field
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
$$
is rotation free it follows from Stokes' theorem that

- $I$ is zero for all closed curves $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^2$.
- Sketch of proof: take a surface in $\mathbb R^\color{red}{3}$
  whose boundary is $\gamma$ in the $x$-$y$-plane.
- It is hard to believe that you could check numerically that there
  are examples where $I\not=0$. If so it is probably due to the fact
  that numerically it is hard to distinguish very small numbers from zero.
  Please elaborate.
- A reasonable application of Schwarz' inequality could be done to (2) which gives however only a trival inequality:
  \begin{align}
  0=I^2&\le\textstyle\Big(\int_a^b\frac{|\gamma(t)|^2}{|\gamma(t)|^2}\,dt\Big)\Big(\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|^2\,dt\Big)\\
  &=\textstyle(b-a)\int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|^2\,dt\,.\tag{3}
  \end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree with the calculations leading to (1); this is exactly what I wrote in the "EDIT" part of my original question. Concerning the expression of $I$ you do not understand: it is only the result of a change of variable, we now take $\theta$ rather than $r$ as the independent variable. $r$ can perfectly be seen as a function of $\theta$ (and so its derivative $dr/d\theta$ is defined); the integral only expresses that we consider small increments of $\theta$, each time computing the quantity being the integrand and summing.

Comment: Thanks for agreeing with me on (1). Note however that the numerator in the integrand is identically zero and that $r$ is constant. I don't see how we could change from $d\theta$ to $dr$ .

Comment: I have discussed with a colleague. He perfectly agrees with the integral you do not understand just above; but has a problem with the other one: $I=\oint_{r_0}^{r_0}\frac{dr}{r}\sin^{2}\theta(r)$. I am going to explain that a bit more in an answer to my post.

Comment: Concerning your last comment: perhaps it is answered by my answer to the original post?

Comment: It will take me a bit of time to digest your answer below. In the meantime, since I am always happy to learn something new: you agree with (1) and your colleague agrees with (2) ? Are you saying they should be equal ?

Comment: We both agree with your (1) and (2) above. But he does not agree with the following integral in my original post $I=\oint_{r_{0}}^{r_{0}}\frac{dr}{r}\sin^{2}\theta(r)$ because $\theta$ is not a (single-valued) function of $r$ but e.g. of $\vec{r}$ as I explain in my answer to my original post.

Comment: Note that (2) is not my equation. It is from the original post and troubles me. (1) is clearly zero and (2) doesn't look like it is. Very confusing.

Comment: Ok, according to you, for a circle, what is the value of $dr/d\theta$ in (2)?

Comment: It is zero because $r$ is constant. Strange way of expressing zero though.

Comment: Two remarks about the edition of your answer: (1) The Stokes' theorem can be applied on your case because $\vec{r}/r=\hat{r}$ has no singularity at the origin. But it cannot be applied if you consider for instance $\vec{r}/r^{2}$ (2) I have checked numerically that MY $I$ is not zero where I have chosen $r(\theta)$ somewhat randomly (MY $I$ is defined in the original post). If I remove $\sin^{2}\theta$ from the integrand it of course becomes zero. This is not a numerical effect.

Comment: On Sept. 13 at 9:27 you wrote in a comment to the OP that your $I$ is "of the type" $\oint\frac{\hat{r}\cdot d\overrightarrow{r}}{r}$. If you want another $I$ now it is time or me to drop out. Thanks .

Comment: Except if I am wrong the $I$ in my original post contains $\sin^2(\theta)$ so it is not of the type you mention. It is of the type you mention if $\sin^2(\theta)$ is removed from the integrand.